# XML installation seems to be failing and not load on R

Tags: r, xml

While installing and trying to load some packages for biological data analysis, I kept getting an error message of

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DESeq2’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘XML’
```

Then I manually installed the XML package:

```
install.packages("XML")
```

it printed this:

```
There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary   source needs_compilation
XML 3.99-0.4 3.99-0.5              TRUE
Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) yes
installing the source package ‘XML’
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/XML_3.99-0.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 968563 bytes (945 KB)
downloaded 945 KB

* installing *source* package ‘XML’ ...
** package ‘XML’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/rp/6tc118312dd069l9827kcfk40000gq/T/RtmpiQB0wX/R.INSTALLd016cd4140e/XML':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘XML’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/XML’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘XML’ had non-zero exit status
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/rp/6tc118312dd069l9827kcfk40000gq/T/RtmpZZUrSn/downloaded_packages’
```

And then when I loaded the package with library(XML):

```
Error in library(xml) : there is no package called ‘xml’
```

This has been happening for many other packages like data.table, etc

Comment: When it asked you "Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?" try saying "no" instead. Also note that pacakge names are case sensitive. `library(xml)` is different from `library(XML)` but it looks like the install failed so neither one would work.

Comment: My advice is: when asked "Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?" just select No. It is rarely worth the extra time to installed the very latest version and usually the binary is updated within a few days anyway.

Comment: Thank you, selecting "NO" when asked that, immediately installed the package. Is there a reason why these packages aren't automatically downloaded? Many of my colleagues had these packages automatically downloaded with the same version of RStudio and R.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the C compiler not working:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
```

Try to install a previous version (e. g: `3.99-0.4`) and/or do it manually.

Download from Cran: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/XML/

You can install the package manually using the following command

```
install.packages('package.tar.gz', lib='destination_directory_of_downloaded_package',repos = NULL)
```

See the help of `?install.packages`, for further description.

Check if package is available after installation:

```r
installed.packages()[1:5,]
```